# GoBack(), DataBinding and page validation

Tags: c#, validation, data-binding, uwp

In a MasterDetail like page on the detail part it is possible to edit within some TextBoxes. When I select a new item in the master part I have to check validity of all input. Also, when pressing the hardware back button.

My problem is, when I check with CanGoBack I get the answer true, then I call GoBack. Before calling GoBack I'm able to let the page check it's validity and returning false in case it is invalid. Then I do not call GoBack. So far so good. Unfortunately if a TextBox has still the focus from the last input, the LostFocus is only called after GoBack and so the Bindings from that control aren't written back to the model when I check the validity, since it is checked before GoBack.

Is it possible to forbid the GoBack going back somehow?

Determining the control with the focus and call it's BindingManger to update the bindings does not work, since the focus is already on the new selected item of the listview in the master part. And also since I use compiled binding, I have no BindingExpressions I could invoke manually.

Another try was to call Bindings.Update() before the validity check, which is available extra for compiled bindings. But this method works silly. It first writes all the values into the view and then after back to the viewmodel. Thus it overrides my input.

Does someone have an idea how to handle input validation on pages correctly and forbidding GoBack when they are invalid?

Comment: Maybe you could try to focus another element using AnotherElement.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic); before calling GoBack(); so the Bindings should be updated

Comment: Thx, I will give it a try, but what is "another"? I would have to determine what control has the focus, since the "other" could be the one also I have to update. And when I determine the Control, which has the focus, then the selected item of the ListView is returned. And I do not know, if settung the focus to a hidden control will work. But I will try it.